# How to download latest file from FTP suing cURL on Filemaker

Tags: curl, ftp, filemaker

I can already successfully hit my FTP and download files to a container field which is great, however what would I use to ensure I only download the newest file out of a bunch of similarly named files?

I have BAT scripts that use maxage, but using cURL is new to me and I am struggling to find documentation to aid me, any suggestions welcome.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a lot of documentation on CURL, standard or FileMaker.

Look into -z option. It can compare local file with the remote or specify the minimum modification date.

Another option is   -I or --head

This will only return http header and for ftp you will only see the file size and modification time.